# Android - How to determine whether coordinates lie on road in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, location, coordinates

I need to make a check in my application that determines whether the given coordinates lie on road or not in Google Maps.

Is there any function in Google Maps API that can aid me with that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a GPS Lat/Lng point lies on a road in Google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208728/check-if-a-gps-lat-lng-point-lies-on-a-road-in-google-maps)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know this can't be done using the Google Maps API.

I think your best bet is to use a crowd-sourced dataset such as [OpenStreetMap (OSM)](http://www.openstreetmap.org/).

You'd need to set up your own spatial database (e.g., [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/)) and import OSM data into the database.

Then, you'd create a server-side API (hosted in a web server such as [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi) or [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/)) to receive the mobile phone's current location, buffer the location with a certain radius to give you a circular polygon, and do a [spatial query via PostGIS](http://www.bostongis.com/postgis_intersection_intersects.snippet) to determine if the buffer intersects any roads (e.g., ways with labels of "highway=primary" or "highway=secondary", depending on what road types you want to include - see [this site](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Highway)), and return the true or false response to the phone.

**EDIT Aug 2015**

There is now a method in the [android-maps-utils library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) called `PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath()` that would allow you to do this type of calculation within your Android app itself, assuming you have the set of points that make up the road (or any other line).

Here's what the code [looks like in the library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java#L146):

```
   /**
     * Computes whether the given point lies on or near a polyline, within a specified
     * tolerance in meters. The polyline is composed of great circle segments if geodesic
     * is true, and of Rhumb segments otherwise. The polyline is not closed -- the closing
     * segment between the first point and the last point is not included.
     */
    public static boolean isLocationOnPath(LatLng point, List<LatLng> polyline,
                                           boolean geodesic, double tolerance) {
        return isLocationOnEdgeOrPath(point, polyline, false, geodesic, tolerance);
    }
```

To use this library, you'll need to add the library to your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
}
```

Then, when you have your point and your path, you'd need to convert your lat/longs to [`LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) objects (specifically, a `LatLng point` and `List<LatLng> line`, respectively), and then in your code call:

```
double tolerance = 10; // meters
boolean isLocationOnPath = PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(point, line, true, tolerance);
```

...to see if your point is within 10 meters of your line.

See the [Getting Started Guide](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/#start) for this library for more info on how to use it.

Comment: Pro-guard settings for MapUtils ?

Comment: Shouldn't be any different that any other project that uses support libraries and Google Play Services - for example,  see https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/OpenTripPlanner-for-Android/blob/master/opentripplanner-android/proguard.cfg